# Map Custom JdbcTemplate query result in an Object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I new in java and try to use spring framework. I have a question. 
By example, I have table :

1. employee (id_employee, name)
2. employee_product (id_employee_product, id_employee, product_name)

if I select an employee data from my Employee table, I can map it in a POJO model User and define the tables structure in that model, like this:

```
public class Employee {
    private final int id_employee;
    private final String nama;

    public Employee(int id_employee, String nama){
        this.id_employee = id_employee;
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id_employee;
    }

    public String getNama() {
        return nama;
    }
}
```

And this is the map from jdbcTemplate:

```
final String sql = "SELECT id_employee, nama FROM employee";
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (resultSet, i) -> {
    return new Employee(
            resultSet.getInt("id_employee"),
            resultSet.getString("nama")
    );
});
```

That is clear example for select data from 1 table.

My question is, how to map data from query if my data is custom query? Such us using join and select custom field from that tables, Am I need to create POJO every query?

Sometimes I need to select only `employee.id_employee`, and `employee.name` field from my employee table.

And in another controller I need to select `employee.id_employee` from my `employee` table.

In another case, I need only select `employee.name`, and `employee_product.product_name`

Is there an alternative to map the data without creating POJO for every case?

Comment: You can use JPA for accessing data. See details here https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.jooq.org/ there every query returns a record

Comment: The query doesn't matter, the result matters. You don't need to map every table you use in the query, you only need to map the end-result of your select.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you give me an example?

Comment: @Eklavya okay but how to do it? Can you give me an example?

Comment: In the doc there is an example also

Comment: You already have a sample in your own code. As stated only the result matters and for this result you should use a dto not for all the underlying tables.

Comment: @AdiSparta Your doubt got cleared ? If not i will post code. You can do that with BeanPropertyRowMapper.

Comment: @VinayHegde I'm a little confused. Can you help me with an example with BeanPropertyRowMapper? Thanks in advanced

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks, this library also work. I have tried it also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a one POJO combining two tables like this

```
public class Employee {
    private int id_employee;
    private String name;
    private int id_employee_product.
    private String product_name

    //getter and setters  
    //Don't create a constructor its Entiry
}
```

Now by using a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` [Doc Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html) write your repository like

```
public List<Employee> fetchEmployeeProduct(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate("Your_DataSource");
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("Your Query");
    List<Employee> employeeProductList = 
        jdbcTemplate.query(query.toString(), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class));
}
```

Make sure `SELECT` clause in the query and `Employee` POJO's filed name is same.

Once if you execute your query it will automatically map to POJO. You no need to write a custom mapper `BeanPropertyRowMapper`will take care of mapping.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using your solution and it work. But, if I only select `id_employee` and `product_name` and map to that POJO, the other field such us `id_employee_product` and `id_employee` have 0 value. Is this normal? But this work anyway, thanks

Comment: @AdiSparta Yes. Its normal . You can ignore those values.