# Spring JdbcTemplate Map query result to Custom class

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have one custom requirement that has a workaround but I need something like

```
jdbcTemplate.query(query, param, new BeanProperRowMapper<CLASSTYPE>(CLASSTYPE.class)
```

It is returning `List<CLASSTYPE>` object to me but what will happen in the below scenario?

```
class Column { 
    long id;
    String columnName;
}

class AgentColumn {
    long id;
    String columnName;
}

class AgentColumnMapping {
    long id;
    Column column;
    AgentColumn agentColumn;
}
```

When I wanted to populate the AgentColumnMapping I needed to use ResultSetExtractor and override method `extractData()` for a custom class.

Is there anything inbuild in Spring JdbcTemplate to populate the AgentColumnMapping?

Comment: You can use projections in spring to get it mapped

Comment: Thank you @chathura rupasinghe for your reply, but I'm not using JPA for it. I'm using normal spring JDBC template.

Comment: @PravinAbhale see my answer here It may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571357/map-custom-jdbctemplate-query-result-in-an-object/61585801#61585801

Comment: Hello @VinayHegde Thank you for your reply, in my class, there is two instance variable and those are custom classes. How can i populate their values? BeanPropertyRowMapper is only mapped to the instance variables but not instance class variables.